# SpringBoot + Postman @RequestMapping value = "getImage/{imageName:.+}"

Tags: java, spring-boot

[image]I an creating an endpoint with spring boot...i can upload image to folder and save it via postman everythink works good.
i have a problem with get method when i am adding the value @RequestMapping value = "getImage/{imageName:.+}" in postman i add **http://localhost:8080/api/images/getImage/{burger+png}**
is that corect ???

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/images")
public class ImageController {

    @Autowired
    public ImageService imageService;
    @PostMapping(value ="upload")
    public ResponseEntity uploadImage(@RequestParam MultipartFile     file){
        return this.imageService.uploadToLocalFileSystem(file);
    }
    @GetMapping(
            value = "getImage/{imageName:.+}",
            produces = {MediaType.IMAGE_JPEG_VALUE,MediaType.IMAGE_GIF_VALUE,MediaType.IMAGE_PNG_VALUE}
    )
    public @ResponseBody byte[] getImageWithMediaType(@PathVariable(name = "imageName") String fileName) throws IOException {
        return this.imageService.getImageWithMediaType(fileName);
    }
}
```

what should be the correct request url ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like it's reaching the backend fine, but failing to find path. Usually API endpoints end with parameters with a slug or query param. You can try either of the following to see if it works:

```
http://localhost:8080/api/images/getImage/burger.png

http://localhost:8080/api/images/getImage?imageName=burger.png
```

Keep in mind, you want to make sure that file exists at the path it's mentioning at the very top of the `trace` in the JSON response. This may depend on how you uploaded the file and with what name.

Comment: http://localhost:8080/api/images/getImage/burger.png With this worked fine... some times if you work to much mind stack :P